Can't update creation date of an image with imagemagic
I tried to update the creation date of an image with the following command
convert my-image.jpg -set "date:create" "2023-10-26T16:19:51+00:00" output.jpg

but without a success. In the resulting image output.jpg I got the same date as in my-image.jpg.
The both
identify -verbose my-image.jpg
identify -verbose output.jpg

commands display original value "2024-10-26T16:19:51+00:00".
See my blog post for details.
